# How to I format a php array that is returned to javascript via Ajax in this way?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

Currently I'm returning a PHP array via Ajax in the form of:

```
$months = array(November, December, January);
```

Once I return the value to Javascript I need to format it in this way for it to be compatible with a js Library I'm using:

```
var months = [[0, "November"], [1, "December"], [2, "January"]];
```

I tried returning it as an associative array from PHP and json encoding it to which I receive:

```
[["November"],{"1":"December"},{"2":"January"}]
```

Why does the index number 0 disappear once `json_encoded`? And also is this format the same as the one before it?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript will turn associative arrays into Javscript Objects.

The easiest way to get your format would be to use this array format:

```
$months = array(
    array(0, 'November'), 
    array(1, 'December'),
    array(2, 'January')
);
```

That should return the following when it is encoded;

```
[[0,"November"],[1,"December"],[2,"January"]]
```

**Edit:**
In terms of creating it dynamically as requested:

```
$months    = array(); 
$dateRange = array(
    'November' => 1000, 
    'December' => 1500, 
    'January' => 300, 
    'February' => 600
);

$counter = 0;
foreach ($dateRange as $month => $amount) { 
    $months[] = array($counter, $month);
    $counter++; 
} 

echo json_encode($months);
```

Output: `[[0,"November"],[1,"December"],[2,"January"],[3,"February"]]`

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly in this format. If I may ask, how would I create that array structure programatically? The way I did it was by a loop:

$months = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach($dateRange as $month => $amount) {
 $months[] = array($counter => $month);
}

but once I encode that, I once again am left with the format: [["November"],{"1":"December"},{"2":"January"}], that omits the 0 index and uses curly braces.

Comment: @MiguelV Updated the answer with some extra information of how you could construct it in the loop. The main thing is not to make it an associative array with `$x => $y` and just use `$x, $y`

Comment: Thanks, I was doing an associative array instead of two array items. You da best.